# Pusher not sent event with laravel

Tags: laravel

Pusher work if I test it for just test but when I activate it for added new exam it does not work.

I make event class `ExamAddedEvent implements ShouldBroadcast`.

and this code.

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['notifications-channel'];
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'exam-added';
}
```

my layout:

```
   <script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        
        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('99257b25d6fbd6f11efc', {
        cluster: 'eu'
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications-channel');
        channel.bind('exam-added', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                toastr.success('New Exam Added!')
        });
    </script>
```

toastr msdn I use css and js in layout and it works if i move `( toastr.success('New Exam Added!') )` to another `<script>`. It works when I make a page reload but it does not work when I add new exam

this is my `Examcontroller`

```
$exam->update([
                            'active' => 1,
                    ]);


                //    هنا هنفعل البوشر عن طريق ميسود الايفنت واسم الايفنت اللى انشاناه
                    event(new ExamAddedEvent);

                    return redirect( url("dashboard/exams") );
                }
```

why it not work ?

.env everything ok copy past without change .

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all try to help
solve it problem was  in file config/app.php

```
  App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

this was not active

Comment: Sorry to see that no one in the community was able to help out with your original question, and good to hear that you got it working.